# Use a Client Certificate from IIS

Tags: iis-7, delphi-xe, client-certificates, isapi

I have an IIS website that needs to retrieve data from a 3rd party web service. The website is an ISAPI dll writren in Delphi XE 10.2.

The web service has created a self signed client certificate for us to use. I have imported the certificate into the Local Machine store. The Root certificate is in the Trusted Root CA.

The web service returns 403 Access Denied.

I have create a stand alone client outside of IIS. The client works as expected.

I have added code to explicitly add the certificate from the file system. Again the test code works but the ISAPI dll fails to connect.

Here is the code I use to load the certificate from the file system.

```
  Data: Pointer);
var
  HTTPRStore: IClientCertInfo;
  hStore: HCERTSTORE;
  CertContext: PCCERT_CONTEXT;
begin
  HTTPReqResp.InvokeOptions:=[soPickFirstClientCertificate];
  HTTPRStore:=HTTPReqResp as IClientCertInfo;
  try
    hStore := GetCertStore('C:\Certs\ClientDev.pfx', 'xxxx');

    if Assigned(hStore) then
    begin
      CertContext :=
        CertFindCertificateInStore(
          hStore,
          X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
          0,
          CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
          PChar('ClientDev'),
          nil
        );

      HTTPRStore.SetCertStore(hStore);
      HTTPRStore.SetCertName(GetCertInfo(CertContext));
      HTTPRStore.SetCertIssuer(GetCertInfo(CertContext, CERT_NAME_ISSUER_FLAG));
      HTTPRStore.SetCertSerialNumber(GetCertSerialNumber(@CertContext.pCertInfo.SerialNumber));
      TFile.AppendAllText('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logs\test.log', HTTPRStore.GetCertName + #13#10);

      CertFreeCertificateContext(CertContext);
    end
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Cert store not open');
  finally
    HTTPRStore := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Does anyone know why IIS does not send the client certificate?

Comment: what is the sub status code of the error? check that you give site folder and dll to full access for iis users. Run failed request tracing to know more detail about the issue. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and please share a detailed error message snapshot.

Comment: It is a 403.7. It looks like it is a network issue not a programming issue.

Comment: check that your certificate is trusted by the server or not.